# Firebase Swift 3 View user database

Tags: xcode, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have a question, I have written an app where the user can log in and register, with name, email, location and address. How can I get it for the user to display the user info only for this user in a table or as a label?

Does anyone know a good tutorial?

[image: Firebase Database]

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage

class PersoenlicheDatenView: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference?
    var myList:[String] = []
    var handle:FIRDatabaseHandle = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "email").queryEqual(toValue : "test@test.de")

        ref.observe(.value, with:{ (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
            for snap in snapshot.children {
                print((snap as! FIRDataSnapshot).key) 
                self.myTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }) 
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         return myList.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = myList[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is slightly unclear. When a user logs in, do you want to capture *their* node from Firebase and display it to that user? Or when a user logs in do you want to display the data to a different user? The answer would be very different depending on the use case. Oh, and please include your Firebase structure as a TEXT snippet please, no images or links. If we need to use the structure in an answer we would have to retype it and images are not searchable. You can get your Firebase structure through the Firebase console->Three dots on right->Export JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is to display the users own info I would recommend using Firebase Authentication.

Here is some [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/).

Firebase Authentication gives you an easy method to login users, and store their accounts through their UID(It also allows you to log in and out users). So if you have implemented Firebase Authentication you can use this code.

```
let userId = (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!
ref?.child("users").child(userId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            print(snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value as! String)
            print(snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "any place you would like to query from").value as! String)
})
```

I hope you consider this answer as Firebase authentication has done wonders for me and is incredibly easy to use. It takes out all of the hard parts of managing users and speeds the whole process along.